# How do I create a list in Julia?

Tags: julia, typeof

I thought that a lst could be written as following. 
But using the `typeof()` function one can see that its not a list.

```
julia> a = [1,"test", π]
       typeof(a)

Vector{Any} (alias for Array{Any, 1})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you come from Python then what Python calls a list is the same as `Vector{Any}` in Julia in your example.

However, if you are interested in a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) data structure instead then you have it in DataStructures.jl package, see [here](https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/latest/linked_list/).